# Create list based on criteria with formula

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula, match

I have a worksheet that has a list of `employees`, `spouse` and `children` with `date of births`. They are organized together based on the `employees name` in column `A`.

I am looking for a formula that will extract all employees with relationship 1 without creating duplicates as `employees` can have both a `medical` package and a `dental` package.

Here is the current formula I have that extracts every `employee` that has relationship 1 and a `medical` package, but I just want everyone that has a relationship 1:

```
    =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$20,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($2:$20)/(($E$2:$E$20=1)*($F$2:$F$20="MEDICAL")),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Relationship meaning:

```
1 = Employee

2 = Spouse

3 = Children
```

Here is my workbook:
[image]

Desired Result:
[image]

Comment: That formula is wrong. `INDEX($A$2:$A$20,...` needs to be `INDEX($A:$A,...` or the row function needs to be `ROW($1:$19)`. Currently you returning the row position within $A$2:$A$20 so you will be shifted one row  down.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a pivot table.
It will solve the problem of the dental/medical package.

Go to insert -> table -> pivot table

Comment: Completely agree, but I am making the information into a drop sheet and would like a formula instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "drop sheet"?

Comment: Copy the data and paste it on one tab and have all the calculations on a different tab.

Comment: Hery, with the pivot table approach you can have the data in one tab and the calculations on a different tab.